# What are the rules for when zero-sized return types are FFI safe in Rust?

Tags: rust, ffi

I would like to write a zero-sized type family `Invariant<'a>` which invariantly depends on `'a` and which is FFI safe in the precise sense that we can safely transmute from `extern "C" fn(...) -> Invariant<'a>` to `extern "C" fn(...)`, getting a valid function pointer at the end. The corresponding C code would involve a function pointer returning `void`, so I do not require a corresponding zero-sized type to exist on the `C` side. I also want there to be no public way of constructing an `Invariant<'a>`, as the mere existence of an `Invariant<'a>` will prove to me that a particular action has been done. I am uncertain how reliable the `#[deny(improper_ctypes_definitions)]` lint is and whether it can generate false positives or negatives, but I would prefer to be able to pass this lint when I define a function of type `extern "C" fn(...) -> Invariant<'a>`.

All attempts were made using rustc version 1.71.1.

Attempt 1:

```rust
#[repr(transparent)]
pub struct Try1<'a>(PhantomData<Cell<&'a i32>>);
```

This attempt fails the `#[deny(improper_ctypes_definitions)]` lint because my type consists entirely of `PhantomData`. The compiler states the type is "composed only of `PhantomData`".

Attempt 2:

```rust
#[repr(transparent)]
pub struct Try2<'a>((), PhantomData<Cell<&'a i32>>);
```

This attempt once again fails the `improper_ctypes_definitions` lint. The message here is that "this struct contains only zero-sized fields". My hope was that this struct would, because of `#[repr(transparent)]`, be deemed equivalent to `()`, but this is apparently not the case. Reading the documentation for `#[repr(transparent)]`, it is actually not clear what is supposed to happen when all the fields of a struct have size zero.

Attempt 3:

```rust
#[repr(transparent)]
pub struct GenericInvariant<'a, T>(T, PhantomData<Cell<&'a i32>>);
pub type Try3<'a> = GenericInvariant<'a, ()>;
```

It appears this passes `improper_ctypes_definitions`. However, it has the annoying side effect of an extra public type name, `GenericInvariant<'a, T>`, polluting the namespace, when the only thing we actually care about is `Try3<'a>`.

Attempt 4:

```rust
#[repr(transparent)]
struct GenericInvariant<'a, T>(T, PhantomData<Cell<&'a i32>>);

#[repr(transparent)]
pub struct Try4<'a>(GenericInvariant<'a, ()>);
```

Remarkably, this attempt fails `improper_ctypes_definitions` (this is definitely not what I expected given my intuitions on `#[repr(transparent)]`). The error message given is that "this struct contains only zero-sized fields".

Edit: I have since devised the following test code:

```rust
extern "C" fn f(&()) -> Invariant {
    todo!()
}

let g: extern "C" fn(&()) -> () = unsafe {
    std::mem::transmute(f as extern "C" fn(&()) -> Invariant)
};

g(&())
```

and I have run this code using Miri. Miri believes that all my previous attempts result in undefined behavior.

Comment: Nitpick: if you want to avoid having to bring `Cell` into scope just for variance, you can also use `*mut &'a i32`.

Comment: @jthulhu Nitpick: both raw pointers and `Cell` are wrong for variance, because they also force incorrect auto traits. The correct way is `fn(&'a ()) -> &'a ()`, forcing covariance (because of the return type) and contravariance (because of the parameter), resulting in invariance.

Comment: I bet that if attempts 1, 2 and 4 are illegal then attempt 3 is illegal as well, and `improper_ctypes_definitions` not firing for it is a false negative.

Comment: The compiler generated signature for functions returning ZST returns `void`. Now we're left with the question whether this is _guaranteed_. If not, then `improper_ctypes_definitions` should fire for all attempts. If yes, then it being fired is a bug.

Comment: [Opened an issue about this decision](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/115091).